# interface on specific parameters C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, interface

I have a dynamic method(dynamicQuery) that receives an Enum (which stored procedure) and a `Dictionary<string,string>`, which will populate SQLParameters based on the content of the dictionary.

Let's say I have 3 stored procedures in SQL server that takes different parameters
named sp_insert_product, sp_insert_person, sp_insert_house.

How will I force the dictionary to accept the specific strings to pass to the stored procedure based on what the stored procedure accepts?

Another view of comparison. An overloaded dictionary, as you would do with methods.

**EDIT** 
POSSIBLE SOLUTION 
I can probably create a check inside the method, dynamicQuery, to check that if the content of the dictionary, does align with the parameters of the specified stored procedure.

But I want to do the error checking before compile-time, as opposed to run-time checking which would decrease performance

I resorted to ADO.NET

Thank you

Comment: Does it have to be a dictionary? Why not have a class with stored procedure name and an array of DBParameter?

Comment: Do you mean you want to insist that the dictionary has the correct keys/values for the thing it is being targeted for?

Comment: Yeah, don't use a dictionary, get used to creating classes to represent your strongly typed data .

Comment: and what about having 3 different methods for inserting product, person and house? It is easy for the caller ("I want to insert a product here, so let me call `InsertProduct`), and for the method implementation (no need to understand "which insert I have to call?")

Comment: I can use classes instead of the dictionary, and make a class for every procedure. But the main goal is reusability. Which now that I think of it. I do use classes inside the Person, Product and House class to call the dynamicQuery method. But the goal is to limit the probability of missing a parameter in the dictionary.

Comment: In what a code a dictionary is more reusable?, Yes, every new (and old) caller can fill the same dictionary with a bunch of values, but actually every caller will have to know which parameters it needs to pass, and parameters will be different according to which insert_something they want to call. So, using a dictionary<string, string>, you are not getting any real advantage, and in opposite you are forcing yourself to transform every parameter into a string.

Comment: and about limiting the propability of missinig a paramater, it's much easier for a programmer take the declaration of a class and filling each property of it, instead of relying on some knowledge (is it documented somehow?) as "for inserting a product, I need to fill my dictionary with propA, PropB, ProbC and so on"

Comment: I understand. The goal of the assignment is to use the dictionary as it is to write to the database. But I want to create some sort of a check that the correct parameters are fed to the dictionary for the specific stored procedure.

Comment: so it seems you will have to write the "sort of check" you need. But I keep thinking that using a dictionary you are taking the hard (i.e. more error prone) way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use an enum as key for the dictionary.

```
enum Procedures
{
    insert_prod,
    insert_person
};

var dic = new Dictionary<Procedures, string[]>();
```

Comment: That is also a clever Idea. I have refactored my dynamicQuery to the following. 
public bool dynamicQuery(Procedures,Dictionary<string,stirng>); But the problem still exists that the other team member can use the wrong parameters fro the dictionary for that specific query.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do - then that's very hard to do if there is no rigid contract between the sites. But as long as the code that deals with both is close together, it usually isn't an issue, for example:

```
string DoSomething(string username, string value) {
    var dict = new Dictionary<string,string> {
        { nameof(username), username },
        { nameof(value), value },
    };
    SomeHelper.ExecuteSP("sp_somesp", dict);
}
```

Note that the same thing can *also* be done via anonymous types and reflection, for example:

```
string DoSomething(string username, string value) {
    SomeHelper.ExecuteSP("sp_somesp", new { username, value });
}
```

which is pretty-much the approach that ["Dapper"](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper/) takes (except Dapper has a lot of optimization built in to make the reflection not hurt).